# Get data for last 12 weeks oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, common-table-expression

Hello i need to get transaction count and total amount for transactions in last quarter.
i use following to get data for a quarter (last 90 days)

```
WITH date_range as
(SELECT TRUNC(sysdate) - 90 + level AS week_day
FROM dual
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 90),
     the_data
  AS (SELECT TRUNC(systemdate)  AS log_date, count(*) AS num_obj,status AS log_status, nvl(sum(
        CASE
          WHEN VERSION = '1.1'
          THEN nvl(amount/100,'0.0')
          ELSE nvl(amount,'0.0')
        END), 0) AS totalamount
        from transactionlog where ((merchantcode in (
  SELECT regexp_substr('MERC0003','[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) FROM dual
  connect by regexp_substr('MERC0003', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null ) OR 'MERC0003' IS NULL)  AND status  = 'xxxx')
      GROUP BY TRUNC(systemdate),status)   
SELECT TO_CHAR(dr.week_day,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI AM') AS TXNDATE, NVL(trans_log.num_obj,0) as TXNCOUNT,trans_log.log_status,trans_log.totalamount
FROM date_range dr LEFT OUTER JOIN the_data  trans_log
     on trans_log.log_date =  dr.week_day
ORDER BY dr.week_day DESC ;
```

From above, I get 90 days record , as in 90 rows containing transaction count and amount for 90 days,
i need to get data in terms of weeks in quarter. That is, 12 rows containing data for each week which has transaction count and amount in last 12 weeks.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: 90 days =! 12 weeks =! 1 quarter - what exactly do you need?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Domscheit data for last quarter, starting from current date time

Comment: You probably don't want to mix `LEVEL` and `ROWNUM` in your CTE; also, why subtract 90 just to add `LEVEL` to it? Just use `TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) - LEVEL` ... `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 90` (`SYSDATE+1` to get today's date; use `SYSDATE` alone if you only want dates up to yesterday)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRUNC( date_value ,'IW' )` to truncate a date to the start of the ISO week (Monday 00:00) and add multiples of a week in your date range and perform the same truncation in your query:

```
WITH date_range( week_day ) as (
  SELECT TRUNC( sysdate  - 90, 'IW' ) + ( level - 1 ) * INTERVAL '7' DAY
  FROM   dual
  CONNECT BY TRUNC( sysdate  - 90, 'IW' ) + ( level - 1 ) * INTERVAL '7' DAY <= SYSDATE
),
the_data ( log_date, num_obj, log_status, totalamount ) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC(systemdate, 'IW'),
         -- rest of your query
  GROUP BY TRUNC(systemdate, 'IW'),
       status
)   
SELECT *
FROM   date_range dr
       LEFT OUTER JOIN the_data  trans_log
       on trans_log.log_date = dr.week_day
ORDER BY dr.week_day DESC;
```

Comment: i do not understand the code ... kindly let me know what is your 1st select statement doing? 
Its giving following error:

  A <datetime field> (YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND) is
           expected but not found, or a <datetime field> specified the
           <end field> in an <interval qualifier> is more significant
           than its <start field>.

Comment: Updated - to use `INTERVAL '7' DAY`.